# How to pass dynamic values to a GET API request?

Tags: api, get, java

The following GET request passes

```
@GET("api/v1/shades/colors?color=bl")
Call<List<Colors>> getColors();
```

but the following GET request fails.

```
@GET("api/v1/shades/colors?color={colorId}")
Call<List<Colors>> getColors(@Path(StringConstants.COLOR_ID) String colorId);
```

What's the right way to pass a dynamic value to a GET request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using JaxRS web application. You should use this :

```
@GET("api/v1/shades/colors")
Call<List<Colors>> getColors(@Query("color") String colorId);
```

Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html and this: https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Use annotation `@RequestParam`:

```
@GET("api/v1/shades/colors")
Call<List<Colors>> getColors(@RequestParam String colorId);
```

Comment: I get error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'RequestParam'

Comment: @JayHawk did you import `import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;`?

Comment: I am unable to import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam since "springframework" is a unresolved symbol.